# what is the shortcut key for opening a resource in RAD 6.0? Ctrl + Shift + R?

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, rad

This may be a basic question, but I'm still looking for the answer.

I've been using Eclipse IDE for a long time and I know the shortcut ket <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> which will open the resources dialog box. Recently I switched to RAD 6.0 IDE (as per project need), and I could not use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in RAD 6.0. The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> which lists all the keyboard shortcuts, is also not working in my RAD 6.0.

I want to know whether RAD 6.0 does not support these shortcuts keys or is there any other shortcut available for opening a resource in RAD 6.0?

EDIT: When I open the `Java browsing` perspective, the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> is working fine. But it's not working in the Java/J2EE perspecting. Any ideas on how to enable this shortcut key in all the perspectives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the toolbar, select Customise Perspective and make sure 'Open Resource' is checked.

Comment: got it. thanks. In RAD 6.0 it's there in the following location: Customize perspective -> Commands Tab -> Resource Navigation